# Oracle - How to use trigger "after insert" between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I create database. I have tables, which are connected.

> **book**: id_book, title, author, ..., subsidiary(foreign key to table subsidiary)
>
> **borrowing**: id_borr, visitor, ... book(foreign key to table book)
>
> **subsidiary**: id_subs, city, capacity, ...

For now i have:

```
create table subsidiary
(
   id_subs              smallint                       primary key,
   city                 varchar(50),
   capacity             integer
);

create table book
(
   id_book              integer                       primary key,
   title                varchar(1000),
   author               varchar(100),
   subsidiary           smallint                      null,
   FOREIGN KEY (subsidiary) REFERENCES subsidiary(id_subs)
);

create table borrowing
(
   id_borr              integer                       primary key,
   book                 integer                       null,
   visitor              varchar(100),
   FOREIGN KEY (book) REFERENCES book(id_book)
);
```

I would like to behaviour like: ***Book has got a subsidiary. But after insert of borrowing(of some book), book change subsidiary to NULL.***

I found only this example(and similar): http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php , but i am not still sure about that.

Very thank you.

Comment: What you mean to say is that when a new row is inserted into borrowing, subsidiary in book table will be set to null, am I correct? And if so, what operation are you expecting on subsidiary table?

Comment: You are correct, nothing with subsidiary table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want any operation on subsidiary table, you can write a trigger as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_borrowing 
  AFTER INSERT ON borrowing
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE book
     SET subsidiary = NULL
   WHERE id_book = :NEW.book;
END;
/
```